# Show validation error for Radio Boxes if there is none checked when clicking Submit in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

In this example i want to get the Hint "Die Angabe eines Geschlechtes ist erforderlich" if the submit button is clicked and no gender is chosen. How can i reach this with the button?
I thought i could change the 'touched' state of the radio buttons when the Submit Button is pressed, but this is just possible with reactive forms, is it? I am a bit confused about how to trigger the nfIf error to show the hint, when pressing the Submit button.

```
<form name="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="toggleActiveStatus($event)">
      <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="selectedBy" id="female" [(ngModel)]="patient.gender"
             autocoplete="off" value="female" checked #selectedBy="ngModel" required> Weiblich
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="toggleActiveStatus($event)">
      <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="selectedBy" id="male" [(ngModel)]="patient.gender"
             autocomplete="off" value="male" checked #selectedBy="ngModel" required> Männlich
    </label>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="selectedBy.errors?.required && (selectedBy.dirty || selectedBy.touched)">Die Angabe eines Geschlechts ist erforderlich.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<button (click)="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Weiter</button>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with working with template driven forms and there is probably a better way to do this. I did put together a stackblitz that produces the result you're looking for.

Basically you are going to use `@ViewChild()` to grab the template form in the `ts` backing file.  You'll have a `boolean` property to determine if the form has been submitted.  You can then toggle that boolean and check for form validity in your `onSubmit()`.

#### app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild("f", { static: false })
  public form;

  public hasFormBeenSubmitted: boolean = false;
  public patient = {
    gender: ''
  }

  public onSubmit() {
    this.hasFormBeenSubmitted = true;

    // check for form validity
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(this.patient);
  }
}
```

Then in your template you can just call `onSubmit()` when the form is submitted.  You will check for the `boolean` value and the required error in your form control alert message with an `*ngIf`.

#### app.component.html

```html
<form name="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="selectedBy" id="female" [(ngModel)]="patient.gender"
              autocoplete="off" value="female" checked #selectedBy="ngModel" required> Weiblich
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="selectedBy" id="male" [(ngModel)]="patient.gender"
              autocomplete="off" value="male" checked #selectedBy="ngModel" required> Männlich
      </label>
      <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="selectedBy.errors?.required && hasFormBeenSubmitted">Die Angabe eines Geschlechts ist erforderlich.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Weiter</button>
</form>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-padcsk

Comment: Thanks for your fast help! Works fine.